# How can I draw a line across a div, over text, without displacing the text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a series of square divs with text in them, and I need to draw a line across those divs, over the text.  Z-Index is not an option.  Neither is `<strike>`, because it needs to extend across the entire div, not just the text.

What I need is for it to extend across the entire div, but to be ON TOP of the text, as if on a different layer, and I am trying to determine if it is possible without Z-Index.

Comment: Why is `z-index` not an option?

Comment: I am confused. You want the line over the text? Or over the divs? Please include a better description, or ideally a screenshot of the desired outcome. Also, what have you tried to achieve your desired effect?

Comment: You could use absolute positioned `div`s either in the one your text is or in its parent. The div would have 0px height and a 1 px top or bottom border.

Comment: I had idea same as you @MarcellFülöp

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With the help of `:after` - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cX5L5/)

```css
div {
    position: relative;  
}

div:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #c00;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: was thinking the same, used `<strike>` in my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/GQ96a/1/)

Comment: Sorry, by over I meant on top of.

Comment: what do you mean? the `:after` pseudo element ( which is the line here ) is on top of the parent div

Comment: @user1790093 if you modify the height of the `:after` element, you can clearly see that it is above the text:  http://jsfiddle.net/cX5L5/1/

Comment: I feel dumb...I was rather fatigued earlier.  This will do it!  Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 2):

[Link To Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyUF7/)

```
.wrapper {
  position:relative;
  width:110px;
}
.square {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border:2px solid #000;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}
.strike {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:2px;
  background:black;
  top:11px;
  left:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what about a background image as a solution? 
I mean someCSS Code like:

```
.DIV.squarestroke {
 background: url(img_with-line.gif) repeat;
}
```

Comment: the background will run *under* the text

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use text-decoration:line-through it's likely you have padding or margin on your div which is why the line doesn't go all the way across.  This snippet will draw a line the width of the div and through the text preserving your padding or margins.

```
<div style="border:solid 2px black; padding : 100px">
       <div class="strike-through" style="border-bottom : solid 1px red; margin-bottom : -12px;"></div>
       <div style="text-align : center; padding-left:50px; padding-right:50px; border : solid 1px green;">Lorem Ipsum Voluptatem</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

A good old fashion hr might do it:

```
 <hr style="position:absolute; width:50px; top:5px; left:5px;" />
```